# Как нарисовать треугольник по трём сторонам?

Tags: javascript, canvas

У меня будет 3 интупа и баттон. При нажатии на этот батон должен нарисоваться треугольник у которого 3 стороны равны значениям в инпутах. Как это организовать? Нагуглил

```
context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(30, 20);
            context.lineTo(some_value);
            context.lineTo(some_value);
            context.closePath();
```

Но этот способ подходит для рисования, по двум сторонам.

Comment: В `input`-ах какое значение? Длина стороны?

Comment: @ГеннадийЖуров да, прошу прощение что не указал

Comment: Задаёшь от фонаря координаты одной вершины. Задаёшь от фонаря одну из координат второй вершины, и, исходя из длины одной из сторон, считаешь вторую координату. По длинам двух оставшихся сторон считаешь координаты третьей вершины. Рисуешь линии - от первой вершины ко второй, от второй к третьей, от третьей к первой. И идёшь пить пиво...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам надо найти координаты вершин и соединить их отрезками. Пусть одна сторона (например, `A`) лежит вдоль оси `0X`. Тогда её `Y`-координата будет равна `0`. А значит и двух вершин треугольника тоже. Остаётся найти ещё одну вершину и соединить её с концами этого отрезка `A`.

Я бы для начала нашёл углы треугольника. Это можно сделать из двух разных формул поиска площади треугольника: по формуле Герона и зная, что площадь равна произведению длин двух сторон на синус угла между ними.

После этого можно опустить высоту из вершины, координаты которой ищем, и внутри прямоугольного треугольника легко найдём `x`- и `y`-компоненты координаты.

```js
btn.onclick = () => {
    let A = 1 * a.value,
        B = 1 * b.value,
        C = 1 * c.value;
    let p = (A + B + C) / 2;
    let S = Math.sqrt(p * (p - A) * (p - B) * (p - C));
    let SinA = 2 * S / (A * B);
    let alpha = Math.asin(SinA);

    let x = B * Math.cos(alpha),
        y = B * Math.sin(alpha);

    let ctx = img.getContext("2d");

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10 + A, 70);
    ctx.lineTo(10, 70);
    ctx.lineTo(10 + x, 70 - y);
    ctx.lineTo(10 + A, 70);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<input type=text id=a value=30><br>
<input type=text id=b value=70><br>
<input type=text id=c value=60><br>
<input type=button id=btn value="ok"><br>
<canvas id=img width=100 height=80>
```

Матчасть: [Как найти углы треугольника по трем его сторонам](https://www.kakprosto.ru/kak-51875-kak-nayti-ugly-treugolnika-po-trem-ego-storonam)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно будет сначала вычислить координаты каждой точки. Вы можете установить первую точку на [0, 0], а вторая будет на [x1, 0], где x1 - длина первой строки. Третью точку можно рассчитать так:

```js
var AB = 40;
var BC = 50;
var AC = 30;

var A = [0, 0]; // начальные координаты
var B = [0, AB];
var C = [];

// вычисление третьей точки
C[1] = (AB * AB + AC * AC - BC * BC) / (2 * AB);
C[0] = Math.sqrt(AC * AC - C[1] * C[1]);

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(A[0], A[1]);
ctx.lineTo(B[0], B[1]);
ctx.lineTo(C[0], C[1]);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```